# Loading ajax first time on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

On my PHP page I use AJAX to fetch items for an auction, everything is working properly when something is chosen from the dropdown lists (as can be seen from picture 1 [image: problem1]). My problem is that when the page loads for the first time (see second picture [image: problem2]) than nothing happens while I just want the default values of the dropdown list to be loaded in Ajax just like the rest, how do I go around this issue? Note that in the first picture I first selected something else and then selected the default values again, the 2nd picture is the page when i open up my browser and do nothing else.

my code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#filtercatselect").on("change", function() {
        var categoryid = document.getElementById("filtercatselect").value;
        var orderbyname = document.getElementById("filterorderbyselect").value;
        if(categoryid == "")
        {
            categoryid = 0;
        }
        $.post('homefiltering.php', { catid: categoryid, sortname: orderbyname }, function(result) {
                $('#item-container').html(result);
            }
        );
    });
    $("#filterorderbyselect").on("change", function() {
        var categoryid = document.getElementById("filtercatselect").value;
        var orderbyname = document.getElementById("filterorderbyselect").value;
        if(categoryid == "")
        {
            categoryid = 0;
        }
        $.post('homefiltering.php', { catid: categoryid, sortname: orderbyname }, function(result) {
                $('#item-container').html(result);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just place under your code this, to trigger the `change` event on first script execution

```
[--- your code above ---]
$("#filterorderbyselect").trigger('change');

// OR - based on what code you prefer to execute on first page execution
// place both you make two equal ajax calls- thanks to Don't Panic
$("#filtercatselect").trigger('change');
```

Comment: you mean ``ready`` for sure but his exampe code is inside a ``$(function()`` which is equal as ``$(document).ready(``

Comment: I believe this makes two identical AJAX requests, right?

Comment: @Don'tPanic - yeah you are right, i wrote both because i don't know which function he wants to be executed on first pageload - i edit my post to make this clear

Answer (score 0):

How about this? On load you call the functions that I have given names and then assign them for change-event to the dropdowns.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // call these methods on load
    filtercatselectChangeHandler();
    filterorderbyselectChangeHandler();

    // set on-change handlers
    $("#filtercatselect").change(filtercatselectChangeHandler);
    $("#filterorderbyselect").change(filterorderbyselectChangeHandler);
});

function filtercatselectChangeHandler(){
    var categoryid = document.getElementById("filtercatselect").value;
    var orderbyname = document.getElementById("filterorderbyselect").value;
    if(categoryid == "")
    {
        categoryid = 0;
    }
    $.post('homefiltering.php', { catid: categoryid, sortname: orderbyname }, function(result) {
            $('#item-container').html(result);
        }
    );
}

function filterorderbyselectChangeHandler(){
    var categoryid = document.getElementById("filtercatselect").value;
    var orderbyname = document.getElementById("filterorderbyselect").value;
    if(categoryid == "")
    {
        categoryid = 0;
    }
    $.post('homefiltering.php', { catid: categoryid, sortname: orderbyname }, function(result) {
            $('#item-container').html(result);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, but unless I've missed something, both of the functions do exactly the same thing. That being the case, there could just be one function, right?